# How can I change tint color of an image in my SpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, tintcolor

I have an image in my SpriteNode, but the image is black and I have a black background in my app. How can I change the tint color from my image in my SpriteNode?

I tried already this:

```
    retryButton.color = UIColor.white
    retryButton.color = .white
    retryButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    retryButton.tintColor = .white
```

This is my code:

```
    var retryButton: SKSpriteNode!

    retryButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "retryImage")
    retryButton.name = "retryButton"
    retryButton.color = .white
    retryButton.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    retryButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY -   100) 
    self.addChild(retryButton)
```

I want now that the Image I added to the SKSpriteNode is white, but the image is still black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a texture with the image first, and then create your `retryButton` with that texture as a `SKSPriteNode`, following should work:

```
    var retryButton: SKSpriteNode!
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "retryImage")
    retryButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
    retryButton.color = .white
    retryButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY -   100)
    self.addChild(retryButton)
```

Comment: But texture is created with `init(imageNamed:)` too (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/1520391-init))

Comment: Thanks for the reference Robert, yeah you are right, I'm aware. But it seems like if the node is created from a texture which is created with an image, then you can change the color. @RobertDresler

Comment: Really not working on swift 5. It gets to the middle tone between black (original image color) and the color I want. And even so I had to add the line `.colorBlendFactor = 1.0` to see any change at all.